# Making custom functions in R involving summation

Tags: r, function

I am a novice in R asked to compute for a descriptive statistic called dominance (D; expressed as a percentage). D is basically defined as the mean abundance (MA) value of *x* divided by the sum of MA values of *x* to *i*. MA meanwhile is defined as the sum of all values in a vector over the length of the said vector. Here is how I normally approach things:

```
#Example data
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(4, 5, 6)
z <- c(7, 8, 9)

#Mean abundance function
mean.abundance <- function(x){
  N_sum <- sum(x)
  N_count <- length(x)
  N_sum/N_count
}

#Percent dominance function (workaround)
percent.dominance <- function(x, ...){
  MA_a <- (x)
  sum_MA_i <- sum(x, ...)
  (MA_a/sum_MA_i)*100
}

MA_x <- mean.abundance(x)
MA_y <- mean.abundance(y)
MA_z <- mean.abundance(z)
MA <- c(MA_x, MA_y, MA_z)
MA

D_x <- percent.dominance(MA_x, MA_y, MA_z)
D_y <- percent.dominance(MA_y, MA_x, MA_z)
D_z <- percent.dominance(MA_z, MA_x, MA_y)
D <- c(D_x, D_y, D_z)
D
```

That approach alone already gives me the %D values I am looking for. My problem is that my (perfectionist) PI is asking me to compute for the %D values directly using vectors *x*, *y*, and *z* (and not stepwise by means of calculating MA values then using vectors *MA_x*, *MA_y*, and *MA_z* to calculate for %D). I am stumped making a custom function for %D that involves vectors containing raw data; here is a failed attempt to revise said custom function, just to give a general idea.

```
#Percent dominance function (incorrect)
percent.dominance <- function(x, ...){
  MA_a <- sum(x)/length(x)
  sum_MA_i <- sum(x, ...)/length(x, ...)
  (MA_a/sum_MA_i)*100
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the optional data passed with `list(...)` and make the following changes to the function -

```
percent.dominance <- function(x, ...){
  data <- list(...)
  MA_a <- sum(x)/length(x)
  sum_MA_i <- sum(x, unlist(data))/(length(data) + 1)
  (MA_a/sum_MA_i)*100
}

percent.dominance(x, y, z)
#[1] 13.33333

percent.dominance(y, x, z)
#[1] 33.33333

percent.dominance(z, x, y)
#[1] 53.33333
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is of much help. I tried to replicate having the correct outputs using a dataset having 9 variables with 67 observations, but it did not give me the correct values. But since the MA values are essentially proportions having the same denominator, and I am simply adding proportions in sum_MA_i, I tweaked the sum_MA_i in the function you specified to change denominator "(length(data) + 1)" to "length(x)". It then gave me the results that I wanted.